# Restore mysql database from files

Tags: mysql, restore

Consider the following scenario. I have MySQL installed on a Windows Server. All files in this server are backed up to a NAS drive by Acronis. My server is broken down. I re-installed operating system and MySQL server. MySQL server is up now. How can I restore my databases from my backup files? Where are the database files located?

Note: The backup has the whole files of the computer.

Comment: Unless you reconfigured something, the databases live in the `data` folder under where you installed MySQL. Stop MySQL before attempting a file copy and cross your fingers the databases are all recognised when you restart MySQL

Comment: Of course this will depend upon you installing the same version of MySQL now that was installed before